# Get timed embedded text from .3gp in flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, closed-captions

Is it possible to fetch closed captioning from a .3GPP video file from `Flash CS5`?

I'm working with `closed captioning` in `Flash` and was just wondering if there was an easier way of doing things. Embedding the timed text within the video file itself is much easier I think, but I don't know how to retrieve the data in `Flash` from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for the [NetStream.onTextData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event%3aonTextData) "event", this should give you access to embedded timed text data.